# Make menu item non clickable in vb.net

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, sitemap

One of the sitemap node is defined as:

```
<siteMapNode title="Parent">
<siteMapNode url="~/Child1.aspx" title="Child1" />
<siteMapNode url="~/Child2.aspx" title="Child2" />
</siteMapNode>
```

The requirement is - the node "Parent" should not be clickable. We are using the Sitemap in a web user control - menu.ascx file. the code is as below

```
<asp:Menu ID="Menu1" runat="server" BackColor="#7C6F57" DataSourceID="SiteMapDataSource1" Font-Bold="True" Font-Names="Verdana" Font-Size="0.8em"
    ForeColor="#F7F6F3" Height="1px" Orientation="Horizontal" StaticSubMenuIndent="10px" MaximumDynamicDisplayLevels="4" BorderColor="Black" BorderStyle="Solid" BorderWidth="1px" StaticDisplayLevels="2">
    <StaticMenuItemStyle HorizontalPadding="5px" VerticalPadding="2px" />
    <DynamicHoverStyle BackColor="#F7F6F3" ForeColor="#7C6F57" />
    <DynamicMenuStyle BackColor="#7C6F57" BorderColor="Black" BorderStyle="Solid" BorderWidth="1px" />
    <StaticSelectedStyle BackColor="#5D7B9D" Font-Size="Small" />
    <DynamicSelectedStyle BackColor="#5D7B9D" ForeColor="#FFFFC0" />
    <DynamicMenuItemStyle HorizontalPadding="5px" VerticalPadding="2px" />
    <StaticHoverStyle BackColor="#7C6F57" ForeColor="White" />
</asp:Menu>
<asp:SiteMapDataSource ID="SiteMapDataSource1" runat="server" />
```

To make the "Parent" node not clickable we have not provided the URL attribute to the node. But still the "Parent" node could be clicked and would result in 404 - File or directory not found. 
The URL would be http://localhost:2550/%23

The following JavaScript code was added in menu.ascx to make the node not  clickable.

```
<script type="text/javascript">  
    window.onload = function () {
        var menuTable = document.getElementById("<%=Menu1.ClientID%>");
        var menuLinks = menuTable.getElementsByTagName("a");      
        for (i = 0; i < menuLinks.length; i++) {
            if (menuLinks[i].nameProp == "%23") {
                menuLinks[i].onclick = function () { return false; }
            }
        }
    }
</script>
```

This method worked fine in IE8, but the issue still persists in Chrome browsers.

Please suggest what else has to be done to make the "parent" node not clickable.

Comment: IE8? ouch :D Is this a requirement? You could check how to use the clickEvents preventDefault maybe?

Comment: what do you mean by non-clickable: Invisible or grayed out?

Comment: by non clickable i mean. it should be shown as any normal menu item but when i click on the menu item i dont want any action to take place. Currently it give 404 - File not found error.

Answer (score 0):

Modern browsers prefer the e.preventDefault() on the calling event, just change your function to do it in the following way

```js
function runMe() {
  var menuLinks = document.getElementById('menu').getElementsByTagName('a'),
    i, len, handler = window.attachEvent || window.addEventListener,
    ev_prefix = window.attachEvent ? 'on' : '';
  for (i = 0, len = menuLinks.length; i < len; i++) {
    if (menuLinks[i].name === '#') {
      handler.call(menuLinks[i], ev_prefix + 'click', function(e) {
        if (e === undefined) {
          e = window.event;
        }
        if (e && e.preventDefault) {
          e.preventDefault();
        }
        return false;
      });
    }
  }
}

runMe();
```

```html
<div id="menu">
  <a href="./">Working</a>
  <a href="./" name="%23">Not working</a>
</div>
```